# Flash caching

Tags: flash, caching

I have a flash movie that dynamically generates urls based on some params. Snip:

```
<object data="images/flash/header.swf?button=1&lang=foo...
```

The problem is that both IE and FF do not get the swf from cache when the params differ.

How can I get around this and make the browser cache the swf, ignoring the params values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realised I can use flashvars - http://cyrilgodefroy.com/fr/index.php/2007/10/25/112-when-flash-means-no-cache